# SAPUI5 : Expanding and moving appointments in PlanningCalendar

Tags: drag-and-drop, sapui5, appointment

I made a planning with workers and their tasks, now I need to improve it by easily modifying the appointments. I would like to know if it is possible to do some dragging and dropping to move the tasks and change their duration ?

I think it is, but everything I find on the internet doesn't fit to an mvc application. Since the planning is in a single view, I would like to do my job only in the view's controller.

**EDIT :** In my controller, I did this code :

```
onInit : function(){
        var oView = this.getView();

        //load jquery libraries for drag n drop
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-widget");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-mouse");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-draggable");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-droppable");

        //make the appointments drag n droppables
        var oAppointment = oView.byId("draggable");
        var idAppointment = oAppointment.getId();
        oAppointment.onAfterRendering = function(){
            $("#"+idAppointment).draggable({
                cancel:false
            })
        };
    }
```

The `draggable` id is set to my CalendarAppointments like this :

```
<appointments>
     <unified:CalendarAppointment
          id="draggable"
          startDate="{CustomModel>EarlSchedStartdate}"
          endDate="{CustomModel>EarlSchedFindate}"
          title="{CustomModel>Description}">

     </unified:CalendarAppointment>
 </appointments>
```

In a separate project with just a single button, it works, but it doesn't for my planning appointments.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard, in theory: use `jquery-ui-draggable/droppable`, assign the `draggable()` and `droppable()` event handlers to the `CalendarAppointment` and/or `PlanningCalendar` objects, and in these handlers do your magic to update the underlying model

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize the draggable function, but maybe I don't use it in the same place. In my onInit() function, I got the right namespaces with `jQuery.sap.require` ; then I did this : `oView.byId("draggable").draggable();` ; then I got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: oView.byId(...).draggable is not a function`

Comment: I've edited my post if my explanations aren't clear enough.

Comment: No; I don't think you can attach the `draggable()` to the SAPUI5 control; only to the DOM / jQuery object. I.e. you should have something like this: `this.byId("yourControl").onAfterRendering = function() { this.$().childern().draggable({ /* some options */ drag : function(event, ui) { // your logic here }); };`

Comment: What do you mean by "your logic here" ? What I do when dragging my control ?

Comment: Exactly; when you drag an item, then of course the lane and/or times change, so you need to update your model accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116373/discussion-between-nicaps-and-qualiture).

Answer (score 1):

We got Drag and Drop working nicely with the PlanningCalendar by extending the control.

IMO doesnt make sense to do this kind of DOM logic in a controller.

> "Dom Manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or
>   anywhere else but in directives"

AngularJS best practice, replace directive with control or component for UI5

jQuery UI doesnt support touch, so couldn't be used in a phone, tablet or touch screen, road tested lots of alternative Drag and Touch libraries, some cool stuff out there, mostly overkill for what was needed, went native JS and standard SAPUI5 control event handling as much as possible, fallback to jQuery where needed.

In the PlanningCalendar - 
Added an event delegate to onAfterRendering of an Appointment, conditionally added the element styles like draggable and mouse cursors for resizing etc.

Added similar event delegates to the CalendarRow controls, again easy to do within the PlanningCalendar, they set up droppable areas and manage time collisions etc.

A lot of learning was had studying the source for KendoUI Scheduler and Widjimo Events Calendar, both work nicely with OData. Suggest anyone who has to add features not in SAPUI5 go look at these and similar UI libraries for inspiration.

I am pretty happy with the end result, works seamlessly with OData V2 running Batch, missing a ghost feature (some code in sap.ui.dt.plugin.DragDrop for this, never got round to adding it) and promises for handling events via a controller or callback etc

Comment: Thank you but since I am french, I hardly understood what you wrote ^^" To summarize, I need **1)** to put my code in my index.html, between <script> beacons, because it shouldn't be in a controller ; **2)** use another library because touch is not supported by jQuery ? ; **3)** ...?

Comment: étendre le contrôle de UI5 sap.m.PlanningCalendar ajouter la logique nécessaire to il

Comment: Is it possible to extend just *sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment* or need I to extend the whole aggregation through *sap.m.PlanningCalendar* ? In both cases, I still haven't achieved the custom control, it requires a deep understanding of how works the framework. However yesterday I found a complete repository on github that provides files of openui, I use it as exemple to end my job : https://github.com/SAP/openui5/